# passing along a Class name as a argument, to be used as a argument later on

Tags: java

```
public CountryComponent(String sorter)throws IOException
{
    String sort = sorter;
    getData(); 
    Collections.sort(countriesList, new sort());

}
```

basically in my FrameViewer class im providing a menu of options for different sorting methods, im stuck on how to pass along the class name for my different comparators as an argument

the above was my test. but the .sort(ob, comparator) is expecting it to be the name of the comparator class

I was originally just going to manually type in the specific class name as the String passed along

ex: `CountryComponent canvas = new CountryComponent(PopSorter);`

then I was hoping it would end up being `Collections.sort(countriesList, new PopSorter());`

I saw some things about instanceOf, but I really didnt understand it, I wasnt too sure what they were trying to do was exactly what I was trying to do

Comment: Learn basic stuff about [Java generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't pass the class name of the sorter you want to use later. Don't pass the class either, because you wouldn't know how to instantiate it. Pass an instance of the sorter:

```
SomeSpecificSorter sorter = new SomeSpecificSorter()
CountryComponent cc = new CountryComponent(sorter);
```

and in the CountryComponent class:

```
private Comparator<Country> sorter;

public CountryComponent(Comparator<Country> sorter) throws IOException {
    this.sorter = sorter;
    getData(); 
    Collections.sort(countriesList, sorter);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer I could grasp the easiest, Im still new to programming. I wasnt even thinking this type of solution, Ive never thought to pass anything beyond a primitive data type as a argument. I need to look up "instance of" things. Thank you, Ill be sure to comment in my code where I was helped, and by who.

Comment: There's a reason why Java objects are called "Objects". They're supposed to be used, shared and passed around like regular, physical object. You can pass a Comparator when you need to sort like you would give a knife to someone who needs to cut something.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the class, then you can use newInstance (assuming empty constructor)

```
public CountryComponent(Class<? extends Comparator> sorterClass)throws IOException
{
        String sort = sorter;
        getData(); 
        Collections.sort(countriesList, sorterClass.newInstance());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an argument definition you should use

```
public CountryComponent(Class sorter) {
  Object o = sorter.newInstance() ; // to call the default constructor
}
```

and call it by `CountryComponent canvas = new CountryComponent(PopSorter.class);`

An alternative is

```
public CountryComponent(String className) {
  Class sorter = Class.forName(className);
  Object o = sorter.newInstance() ; // to call the default constructor
}
```

and call it by `CountryComponent canvas = new CountryComponent("yourpackages.PopSorter");`